# how to integrate mongodb Text Search with a python app?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, flask, pymongo

I am trying to integrate Mongodb Text Search with a python app. For this I have written   the code as per below but i am not getting the results and not any error also.The control is not going inside the search function, can anyone please help me?
    Thank you in adv

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request 
app = Flask(__name__)
import pymongo as pym
c = pym.Connection()
db = c['DbName']
#for searching

@app.route('/search')
def search():
    print "prashant"
    query = request.form['15310773']
    text_results = db.command('text','collection_name',search=query,limit=100)
    doc_matches = (res['obj'] for res in text_results['results'])
    return render_template('search.html','results=results') 

if __name__ == "__search__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to build a list of result objects to iterate in your template, you'll need to change your list comprehension to use square brackets instead of parentheses:

```
doc_matches = [res['obj'] for res in text_results['results']]
```

Next, the second parameter to render_template shouldn't be quoted. Try changing it to

```
return render_template('search.html', results=results)
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: yes thanks a lot iandouglas, i made the changes you told but it still not working. when i run the program I get the following,       * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/    and when I paste this url in the browser i get 404 error as "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Comment: What about http://127.0.0.1:5000/search ? You don't currently have a url route to handle just '/' which makes sense that just http://127.0.0.1:5000/ gives you a 404.